# Check if certain value exists in array, if not check for next value and make sure previous values do not occur

Tags: php

Okay, so I have an array called $arraymaster which is basically an array of Educational codes (from highest to lowest):

```
$arrayedumaster=array("P H D", "Post Graduate", "Professional", "Graduate", "Technical", "ITI", "Under Graduate", "H S C Passed", "S S C Passed", "Upto Ninth", "Upto Fifth", "No Schooling");
```

Now there is a second array listing an individual's qualifications which I have obtained from the database:

```
$arrayedu=explode(',', $edudetail);
```

Some examples of $arrayedu are (an individual can have multiple qualifications):

- Graduate, HSC Passed, Graduate, Professional, Professional
- Professional, SSC Passed
- Post Graduate, Professional, Technical

Etc.
Now I have to ascertain an individual's highest qualification (based on $arraymaster) >> and then do some action on that basis from $arrayedu. Currently I am doing that the long way thus:

```
 if(in_array("P H D", $arrayedu){
  $educode=1;
 }
 elseif(in_array("Post Graduate", $arrayedu) && !in_array("P H D",$arrayedu)){
 $educode=2;
}
 elseif(in_array("Professional", $arrayedu) && !in_array("P H D", $arrayedu) 
&& !in_array("Post Graduate", $arrayedu)){
 $educode=3;
}
elseif(in_array("Graduate", $arrayedu) && !in_array("Professional", 
$arrayedu) && !in_array("P H D", $arrayedu) && !in_array("Post Graduate", 
$arrayedu)){
$educode=4;
}
```

And so on. So basically I am trying to obtain the highest qualification from $arrayedu, is there some easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

The solution using `array_intersect` and `current` functions:

```
$arrayedumaster = [
    "P H D", "Post Graduate", "Professional", "Graduate", "Technical", "ITI", "Under Graduate",
    "H S C Passed", "S S C Passed", "Upto Ninth", "Upto Fifth", "No Schooling"
];
$arrayedu = ["Graduate", "HSC Passed", "Graduate", "Professional", "Professional"];

$highest_edu = current(array_intersect($arrayedumaster, $arrayedu));
print_r($highest_edu);
```

The output:

```
Professional
```

Comment: That is it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect one-line answer has already been provided by RomanPerekhrest, but perhaps this approach can be of inspiration:

```
$arrayedumaster = [
  "P H D", "Post Graduate", "Professional", "Graduate", "Technical", "ITI",
  "Under Graduate", "H S C Passed", "S S C Passed", "Upto Ninth",
  "Upto Fifth", "No Schooling"
];
$arrayedu = [
  "Graduate", "HSC Passed", "Graduate", "Professional", "Professional"
];

$highestedu = count($arrayedumaster);
foreach ( $arrayedu as $value ) {
  if ( ($key = array_search($value, $arrayedumaster)) !== false ) {
    $highestedu = min($key, $highestedu);
  }
}

print_r($arrayedumaster[$highestedu]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sort:

```
$data = array(
    "Graduate", "H S C Passed", "Graduate", "Professional", "Professional"
);

$sortingArr = array("P H D", "Post Graduate", "Professional", "Graduate", "Technical", "ITI", "Under Graduate", "H S C Passed", "S S C Passed", "Upto Ninth", "Upto Fifth", "No Schooling", "ddd");

$result = array(); // result array
foreach($sortingArr as $val){ // loop
    $key = array_search($val, $data);
    if(in_array($val, $data)) {
        $result[$key] = $val; // adding values
    }

}
print_r($result); // print results
```